# Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Hi I'm making an email form,  but I'm having some trouble with typescript.

I got the following error when I use rest props in typescript.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I use rest props in typescript?

↓ Input.tsx code

```
interface StyledProps {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  value: string;
}
interface InputProps extends StyledProps {
  onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onBlur?: () => void;
  reset?: () => void;
}

function Input({
  type,
  id,
  value,
  onBlur,
  onChange,
  reset,
  ...res
}: InputProps) {
  console.log("rest",res); //{placeholder: 'enter email address '}
  return (
    <StyledInput
      type={type}
      id={id}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      {...res}
    />
  );
}
```

↓ parent code

```
  <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div>
        <Input 
            type="id" 
            id="id" 
            value={userId} 
            **placeholder="enter email address"** // I got the error in here
            onBlur={userIdBlurHander} 
            onChange={userIdChangeHandler} />
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: You're not extending the input element props. `interface InputProps extends StyledProps, React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>`

Comment: I did it, but received errors like

Interface 'InputProps' cannot simultaneously extend types 'StyledProps' and 'InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Named property 'id' of types 'StyledProps' and 'InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>' are not identical.ts(2320)

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's because type of `id` in `@types/react` is `id?: string | undefined;` and you're defining it as just `id: string` in `StyledProps`. You can either remove id from `StyledProps` or omit the id type coming from `InputHTMLAttributes`: `Omit<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, "id">`

Comment: Thank you for the help! But I couldn't use this method.
because not only the id prop, 
but all the other props of StyledProps have the same error. 
(ex: type, value, size..)
I just added placeholder props... 